# No puedo acceder a una posicion de JSON

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsonarray

Tengo mi JSON dentro de otro json igual, y necesito saber la posición que se encuentra `POS` pero ninguno de los codigos que he encontrado me funciona, y aunque se que podría manualmente ir en un ciclo for, este json puede contener demasiados valores en algunas ocasiones y no quisiera interar por 30elementos cada vez

```
0: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Y dentro de cada uno

```
[
    0: {Amount: "19.56"}
    1: {Address: "Home"}
    2: {POS: "principal"}
    3: {User: "Santiago"}
]
```

He intentado con `.indexOf("POS")` con `.findIndex("POS")` y otras funciones lambdas que he encontrado, pero siempre me devuelve -1 sin importar nada

Comment: Tienes que tener en cuenta que `.indexOf()` recorre el array hasta encontrar tu objeto, así que hubiera poca diferencia en que lo hicieras con un `for`

Comment: No te vas a encontrar un metodo magico que te facilite todo, debes pensar un poco y adaptar la solucion a lo que necesitas, ejemplo: si tu array no va a cambiar su orden entonces puedes recorrerlo una vez y guardar el index donde se encuentra `POS` de esa manera para obtener `POS` utilizas `array[index_de_pos]`

Comment: Lo que muestras en tu pregunta no es un JSON válido ni tampoco un Array válido. ¿Puedes mostrar la estructura real de lo que tienes y cómo has intentado acceder a ella?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Me presipité disculpa, actualize el json con sus partes

Comment: @SpaceDevelop Sii estoy conciente que quiera que no se tiene que hacer un ciclo, pero preferiria no hacerlo si ya existe algo para encontrarlo

Comment: @MauricioContreras ahorita para mis pruebas sii lo dejo quemado, pero se que el json no siempre va a tener la misma cantidad de cosas, ahorita solo lo limito a las cosas básicas que necesito para mi parte, luego agregamos el resto de cosas y el json crece mucho

Comment: Crece en tiempo de ejecución? o se obtiene de un servidor y no se cambia mas?

Comment: Algo que también tienes que tener en cuenta es que puedes cambiar la estructura de tu JSON, que cada propiedad este dentro de un array es algo complicado de utilizar (Y de leer). Si puedes cambiarlo a `[{Amount: "19.56", Address: "Home", POS: "principal", User: "Santiago"}]` se te haría mucho menos costoso todo, porque solo usarias `json[0].POS` o `json[0]["POS"]`

Comment: @SpaceDevelop de una lambda de amazon, pero ahorita solo recibo estos pocos valores porque todavía estamos trabajando en el resto que deben de devolver, y algunas veces puede o no que lleve ciertos elementos extras... El problema es que se guardan así por una tabla que muestr los datos, tenemos esa estructura ahora, antes sii la teniamos así como dices .POS

Comment: No hay una función que haga lo que quieres, debes hacerla tu mismo. Utilizando `reducer`, `forEach`, `map`, `for` o `while` con cualquiera se puede hacer pero será costoso para el CPU, yo te recomiendo (A visión general porque no conozco para que se utilizará tu json) que actualices tu tabla a como estaba antes, eso es lo mas optimo, te vas ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza y CPU

Comment: Puedes también restructurar tu json a `json[0].POS` cuando se reciba desde la API, costará CPU al inicio porque que tiene que recorrer todo tu array pero después no tendrás que preocuparte por eso

Comment: Ojalá pudiera regresarlo, ya me funcionaba eso antes... Pero los jefes mandan @SpaceDevelop pero gracias... Voy a ver lo de map que nunca lo he usado

Comment: Voy a publicar como respuesta un ejemplo para que te guíes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a acceder a ellos con mucha frecuencia debes convertir todo el array a un objeto, para que así las propiedades estén indexadas y no tengas que estar iterando cada una para ver si es el que estas buscando.

```js
const lambaJSON = [
  [
      {Amount: "19.56"},
      {Address: "Home"},
      {POS: "principal"},
      {User: "Santiago"},
  ],
  [
      {Amount: "13.56"},
      {Address: "Home2"},
      {POS: "principal2"},
      {User: "Santiago2"},
  ]
]

const toJson = lambaJSON.map(arrProps => {
  return arrProps.reduce((a, c) => {
    const key = Object.keys(c)[0]
    return ({...a, [key]: c[key]})
  })
})

console.log(toJson[0].POS)
console.log(toJson[1].POS)
```

Comment: Gracias! Antes de marcarlo como respuesta voy a hacer pruebas, pero esto de map es nuevo para mi, muchas gracias por tu ayuda de igual manera!!

Comment: Analizando un poco el porque decidieron que tu tabla este de esa manera, creo que la utilizan solamente para obtener los valores en una sola pasada, es decir, no tener que estar estableciendo "Pinta POS aqui" si no que leen el array, obtiene el key  y el valor y lo pintan, sin diferenciar cual sea. Si ese fuera el caso entonces esta bien. Si tu quieres hacer lo mismo entonces no será necesario que lo conviertas a objeto

Comment: Developer, pues esto lo necesito para luego hacer un filtrado en esa tabla, necesito obtener en que lugar del json está para poder buscar que coincida con lo ingresado por el usuario y mostrar los resultados

Comment: Me tira el error `arrProps.reduce is not a function`

Comment: La razón es que tu `arrProps` no es un array. Para verificarlo realiza la siguiente prueba: `console.log(Array.isArray(arrProps))`

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza en poner como solucion, la verdad no se que pasaba pero sii era un array, me lo puso en el formato que ya puedo encontrar dinamicamente el parametro, gracias!